# ng-repeat on duplicate key (angular)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

JSON:

```
streams = [{ id: 0,
   codec_type: 'video',
   content: '1920x1040 - H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10' },
 { id: 1,
   codec_type: 'audio',
   content: '5.1(side) - cze - undefined' },
 { id: 2,
   codec_type: 'audio',
   content: '5.1(side) - eng - undefined' },
 { id: 3, codec_type: 'subtitle', content: 'cze - Czech' },
 { id: 4, codec_type: 'subtitle', content: 'eng - English' }];
```

Angular HTML markup:

```
<md-input-container ng-repeat="stream in streams">
  <label>{{stream.codec_type}}</label>
  <md-select ng-model="stream">
    <md-option value="{{stream.id}}">{{stream.content}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

---

Hi, I need find duplicate string on JSON and repeat only ONE select with many options under this (codec_type) duplicate string. Please have you any idea to do this? Thank you

---

### !!! UPDATE !!!

I must redesign JSON and work with objects separatly or something like that

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epXbpm).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be done with two different filters: one to grab a list of unique codec types, and one to grab a list of codecs that fit that type.

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmGONV)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="codec in streams | unique:'codec_type'">
      {{codec.codec_type}}
      <select ng-model="$parent.selected[codec.codec_type]" ng-options="stream as stream.content for stream in streams | codec:codec.codec_type track by stream.id">
      </select>
    </div>
    Selected streams: {{selected}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selected = {
      'video': null,
      'audio': null,
      'subtitle': null
    };
    $scope.streams = [
      {
        id: 0,
        codec_type: 'video',
        content: '1920x1040 - H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10'
      },
      { id: 1,
        codec_type: 'audio',
        content: '5.1(side) - cze - undefined'
      },
      { id: 2,
        codec_type: 'audio',
        content: '5.1(side) - eng - undefined'
      },
      { id: 3,
        codec_type: 'subtitle',
        content: 'cze - Czech'
      },
      { id: 4,
        codec_type: 'subtitle',
        content: 'eng - English'
      }];
  })
  .filter('unique', function () {
    return function (items, id) {
      var filtered = [];
      var ids = {};

      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        if (typeof(ids[item[id]]) === 'undefined') {
          filtered.push(item);
          ids[item[id]] = true;
        }
      });

      return filtered;
    };
  })
  .filter('codec', function () {
    return function (items, codec) {
      var filtered = [];

      angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        if (item.codec_type === codec) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }
      });

      return filtered;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngOptions directive.

Check out the angularJs Documentation [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Example:

```
<select ng-model="stream" ng-options="stream.codec_type for stream in streams>
   <option value=""> Choose Option </option>
</select>
```

There are multiple other forms to use ng-options, the one I used is simply:

```
label for value in array
```

The link I posted will mention and explain each form in depth, so you can choose which one will properly fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for tip I must redesign JSON and now, It"s working CodePen. [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epXbpm)

Answer (score 0):

***CONTROLLER:***

```
var types_array = [];
$scope.isUnique = function (type) {
     if (types_array.indexOf(type) === 1){
         return false;
     } else {
         types_array.push(type);
         return true;
     }
}
```

***HTML:***

```
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="stream in streams">
     <div ng-if=isUnique(stream.codec_type)>
      <label>{{stream.codec_type}}</label>
      <md-select ng-model="stream">
        <md-option value="{{stream.id}}">{{stream.content}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
     </div>
    </md-input-container>
```

Comment: this get me double subtitle and none of audio